# First and second time appearing row id in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Suppose we have a list of ids with date. And we want to know when the ids appeared for the first and the second time. About the first time, I have created a query that is

```
SELECT year, mon, COUNT(id) AS sum_first_id
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ON (id) DATE, id
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY 2, 1
    ) AS foo
GROUP BY 2, 1
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

I think that this works. But how could I find when the ids appear for the second time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have the table `table_x`:

```
select * 
from table_x
order by 1, 2

 id |    date    
----+------------
  1 | 2015-06-04
  1 | 2015-06-05
  1 | 2015-06-14
  2 | 2015-06-05
  2 | 2015-06-08
  2 | 2015-06-10
  2 | 2015-06-17
  2 | 2015-06-22
(8 rows)
```

To select n first element in groups use `row_number()` function:

```
select id, date
from (
    select id, date, row_number() over (partition by id order by date) rn
    from table_x
    order by 1, 2
    ) sub
where rn <= 2

 id |    date    
----+------------
  1 | 2015-06-04
  1 | 2015-06-05
  2 | 2015-06-05
  2 | 2015-06-08
(4 rows)
```

---

It does not appear that your query is correct.

```
SELECT year, mon, COUNT(id) AS sum_first_id -- what is year, mon?
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ON (id) DATE, id
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY 2, 1                           -- should be order by 2, 1
    ) AS foo
GROUP BY 2, 1
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: Year, mon are the extraction of years and month on date, I didn't define that, sorry! What is the rn clause you put, can you explain me??

Comment: `rn`is an alias for `row_number()`. Try `select id, date, rn` in the main query to see its values.